# Simple clarification on probability of events

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am rather new to probability and its concepts and would appreciate a clarification for the following very simple problem, mainly for understanding purposes:
If we had to form a word of 4 letters where only the letters at position 1 and 3 have to be vowels and the other position any other letter(except for vowels), we could compute the probability by:
$$\frac{6 \times 20 \times 5 \times 19}{26 \times 25 \times 24 \times 23}$$

The same probability could also be computed by:

$$\frac{\frac{20!}{(20-2)!}\times \frac{6!}{(6-2)!}}{\frac{26!}{(26-4)!}}$$

Thus the same result could be attained without considering the position of the letters.  Is this due to the fact that they are all equally likely?

Comment: It seems that you are talking about words consisting of different letters. But you don't have this condition, or do you?

Comment: It is true that any arrangement of a specific set of 4 letters is equally likely. Say, ACED or ECAD.  If that helps.